# iOs OpenglES orientation animation clipping

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es

I have set up a storyboard with a custom `GLKViewController` and a single `GLKView`. When I rotate the device the animation doesn't interpolate smoothly, instead it clips parts of the view and the interpolates the rest.

How can I avoid the clipping?

[image]

The problematic part is marked with 3 on the image.

A video of the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z7olh3y9vylv0k8/problem.mov

Comment: possible duplicate of [GLKViewController orientation animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093272/glkviewcontroller-orientation-animation)

Comment: It's not, that question doesn't have any clipping issues.