# GLKViewController rotating size

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I have set up a simple layout with a single custom `GLKViewController`. Inside the `GLKViewController` is a normal `GLKView`. When the phone orientation changes the view is smoothly autorotated and stretched to match the new size of the view.

Is it possible to acquire the width and the height of the `GLKView` while the rotation is still in progress, from the `glkView:drawInRect`: method in my custom `GLKViewController`?

I'm interested in the width and height marked in **blue**:
[image: Example]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid momentary stretching on autorotation of iOS OpenGL ES apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690950/how-to-avoid-momentary-stretching-on-autorotation-of-ios-opengl-es-apps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rotation width and height can be acquired from the presentationLayer of the GLKView:

`CALayer *presentationLayer = [self.view.layer presentationLayer]; 
CGSize layerSize = presentationLayer.bounds.size;`

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18742030/1109997